# Jmeter How to make 2 thread group run parallel but not sharing parameter value between thread?

Tags: testing, jmeter, parallels

I have a situation like this:

```html
Test Plan
   Thread Group 1
      var A = 1 ( User parameters)
      HTTP request 1
      HTTP request 2 

   Thread Group 2
      var A = 2 ( User parameters)
      HTTP request 3
      HTTP request 4
```

I know that I can use "Run Thread Groups consecutively" to make these 2 thread run parallel. However, the problem is, because they are running parallel, sometimes var A=2 got recognized in Thread Group 1, and thus make the test case fail. What I ask, is there any way that I can still run these threads parallel and still make sure that the parameter values of these threads won't affect on each other? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different name for the variable so that there is no conflict.
Something like below:-

```
Test Plan
   Thread Group 1
      var A = 1 ( User parameters)
      HTTP request 1
      HTTP request 2 

   Thread Group 2
      var B = 2 ( User parameters)
      HTTP request 3
      HTTP request 4
```

From the jmeter documentation:-

> If you have more than one Thread Group, **make sure you use different
>   names for different values**, as UDVs are shared between Thread Groups.
>   Also, the variables are not available for use until after the element
>   has been processed, so you cannot reference variables that are defined
>   in the same element. You can reference variables defined in earlier
>   UDVs or on the Test Plan.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it is almost impossible for me. My script contain a lot of similar scenarios. Using different var will cause confusing alot because some step are the same between scenarios

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) scope is limited to current Thread Group only so the situation where 2nd Thread Group is reading the values from 1st Thread Group [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) element is either a bug in JMeter or your test fails for a different reason. For example not having a User Parameters element in 2nd Thread Group I'm not getting anything as the variable value:

[image: JMeter User Parameters]

I would recommend double checking expected variable A values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination, perhaps your configuration is vague.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, my situation is in Thread Group #2 I also define Var A = 20. It is different in your picture, when you only define Var A in 1 thread. My actually test case is bigger. so this issue is actually happening. Please help me review it. Thank you!